# random float numbers and their mean and standart deviation

Tags: python, numbers, mean

how to get a list of 1000 random float numbers without dublicates and find their mean value in python?

```
import random
rnd_number=random.random()
def a():
        l=[]
        m=1
        for i in range(1000):
                l.append(rnd_number)
        return l
        for i in l:
                m=m+i
        return m//b
print (a())
```

i am probably wrong with returning l before the other operation but when the code works there are 1000 of the same float numbers on the screen

Comment: You need to call `random.random` *inside* the loop (for every i). Otherwise you're doing 
 what's humorously being depicted here: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Also, everything in your function after the `return l` statement does not get executed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would help!

```
import numpy as np
import random

N=10
# number of digits you want after the .dot sign
# more digits .dot ensure mo duplication
Npts=1000
# number of random numbers
num=[]
# initialize the array
for m in range(1000):
    nm=round(random.random(), N)
    # local variable to take the random numbers
    num.append(nm)
    # append the random number nm to the original num array
print(num)
# printing the random numbers

# Let's check is there is a duplication or not
my_num=set(num)
if len(num)!=len(my_num):
    print("Duplication in the array")
else:
    print("NO duplication in the array")

# Calculating mean
avg=sum(num)/Npts
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have distinct random numbers, you have to draw number on every loop iteration. To avoid duplicates you can use set, which stores unique values.

```
import random

def a():
    mySet = set()
    while len(mySet) < 1000:
        mySet.add(random.random())
    return mySet

print(a())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def a():
        s=0
        m=0
        l=[]
        for i in range(1000):
                rnd_number=random.random()
                l.append(rnd_number)

        for n in l:
                m=m+n
        m=m/len(l)
        for k in l:
                s=s+(k-m)**2
        s=(s/len(l))**(1/2)
        
        return l,m,s
print (a())
```

i did like this and got the right answers for both the mean and standart devaiation of 1000 random float numbers
(i checked it with 4 actually but i think it is gonna work for 1000 too)